# ZEVO ZFS and Aperture

Tags: aperture, macos, zfs

I'ld like to use ZEVO (ZFS) on my Storage-Device. There shall the Aperture-Library be stored.

Are there any issues using an Aperture - Library on ZFS formatted device.

Thanks allot

Answer (score 1):

You can't run an Aperture Library from a device that's not formatted Mac OS Extended (Journaled).

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3509

What can work is running a Referenced Library with the Library on an appropriately formatted disk and the Masters stored elsewhere.

Another workaround: Make a Disk Image formatted Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and store that on your device.